# C++ Reading A Header File One Time Though Info Required Across Multiple .cpp Files

Tags: c++, class, variables, static, header

my friend and I are learning C++ together and we have a question. We have created a header file that contains a class which uses static variables and static functions, these functions and variables need to be accessible to a total of 2+ .cpp files but because we are initializing the static variables in the header the header file can only be read one time (due to static the variable initializations).

We have tried only including the header file in our MainFunction.cpp file but the other .cpp files have no ability to use the static variables and functions if we do this. Including the header file in (currently) both .cpp files that require the functions/variables results in a wide array of link errors due to the static variables being initialized multiple times.

Here is the Header File which contains the class and the static variable initialization:

```
//PlayerStatistics.h
// Classes
class PlayerStatistics
{
public:
    // Functions To Change Player Statistics
    static void SetStats(short int HitPoints, short int MagickaPoints, short int Fatigue, short int Damage, short int Defense, short int Dodge, short int Block, short int SpellCastChance);
    static void SetLevel(short int Experience, short int Level);
    static void SetExperience(short int Experience);

    // Player Statistics
    static short int HitPoints;
    static short int MagickaPoints;
    static short int Fatigue;
    static short int Damage;
    static short int Defense;

    // Chance Based System Player Statistics (Relies on Fatigue Level)
    static short int Dodge;
    static short int Block;
    static short int SpellCastChance;

    static short int Experience;
    static short int Level;
};

// STATIC VARIABLES
short int PlayerStatistics::HitPoints = 20;
short int PlayerStatistics::MagickaPoints = 20;
short int PlayerStatistics::Fatigue = 20;
short int PlayerStatistics::Damage = 20;
short int PlayerStatistics::Defense = 20;
short int PlayerStatistics::Dodge = 20;
short int PlayerStatistics::Block = 20;
short int PlayerStatistics::SpellCastChance = 20;
short int PlayerStatistics::Experience = 0;
short int PlayerStatistics::Level = 1;
```

And the 2 .cpp files that require access:

## 1:

```
//PlayerCharcter.cpp
void PlayerStatistics::SetLevel(short int Experience, short int Level)
{
Experience = Experience;
Level = Level;
}

void PlayerStatistics::SetStats(short int HitPoints, short int MagickaPoints, short int Fatigue, short int Damage, short int Defense, short int Dodge, short int Block, short int SpellCastChance)
{
HitPoints = HitPoints;
MagickaPoints = MagickaPoints;
Fatigue = Fatigue;
Damage = Damage;
Defense = Defense;
Dodge = Dodge;
Block = Block;
SpellCastChance = SpellCastChance;
}

void PlayerStatistics::SetExperience(short int Experience)
{
Experience = PlayerStatistics::Experience;
}

void AddExperience()
{
// This is a Testing Function to test the Level Up system and should be removed once Creatures
// are added to the game, or it can be edited to include proper experience points given for
// killing curtain enemies.

short int GetExperienceNumber;
std::cout << "How many experience points do you want? \n";
std::cin >> GetExperienceNumber;

PlayerStatistics::Experience = (PlayerStatistics::Experience += GetExperienceNumber);
std::cout << GetExperienceNumber << " Experience Points Added! \n \n \n \n \n";
}
```

## 2:

```
//WordBank.cpp
        std::cout << "\n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n"
        << PlayerName << "'s Character Sheat! \n \n \n"
        << "Level: " << PlayerStatistics::Level << "\n"
        << "Experience: " << PlayerStatistics::Experience << "\n \n \n"
        << "Health: " << PlayerStatistics::HitPoints << "\n"
        << "Magicka: " << PlayerStatistics::MagickaPoints << "\n"
        << "Fatigue: " << PlayerStatistics::Fatigue << "\n"
        << "Attack: " << PlayerStatistics::Damage << "\n"
        << "Defense: " << PlayerStatistics::Defense << "\n"
        << "Dodge Skill: " << PlayerStatistics::Dodge << "\n"
        << "Block Skill: " << PlayerStatistics::Block << "\n"
        << "Spell Casting Skill: " << PlayerStatistics::SpellCastChance << "\n"
        << "\n \n \n \n \n \n \n" << "To Continue Type Any Key In And Hit Enter" << std::endl;
```

We need to #include this header file in these 2 .cpp files (with 2 more planned that will require access to this class as well) but only actually read the header file one time (so we can avoid reading the static variable initializations more then once). We are trying to steer clear of constructors (mainly for the ease of use with statics but also for our learning purposes). We have read about Header Guards but we can't figure out how to make them work with this problem.

Any tips/advice you have will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Look up "header guard" or "include guard".

Comment: Hmm, we are trying to figure out the inner-workings of Header Guards and such now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably put only declaration of variables in your header files (and those should be extern, not static, global variables, or static member variables with external linkage). So keep having static member variables declarations like (in your `PlayerStatistics.h` header file)

```
class PlayerStatistics {
   /// ....
   static short int HitPoints;
};
```

(it is a static member variable declaration with external linkage)

Then you can put definitions like

```
short int PlayerStatistics::HitPoints = 20;
short int PlayerStatistics::MagickaPoints = 20;
short int PlayerStatistics::Fatigue = 20;
```

in one single implementation file (often conventionally the one containing `main`, e.g. some `main.cpp`).

You should probably put [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your header file, that is starting it with

```
#ifndef PLAYER_STATISTICS_INCLUDED
#define PLAYER_STATISTICS_INCLUDED
```

and ending it with

```
#endif /*PLAYER_STATISTICS_INCLUDED*/
```

I strongly suggest you to study the source code of some existing C++ free software application (e.g. from http://freecode.com/ or other free software collection). This will teach you a big lot.

Comment: Very sorry! I accidentally clicked the "Post is not helpful button" it was an honest mistake!

I like your suggestion of reading other people's code and we will begin to do so thank you, as for your suggestion on how to fix the problem at hand could you go into a bit more detail? We assumed you mean replace "static short int HitPoints;" with "extern short int HitPoints" etc. but this only results in an error stating the extern type isn't allowed for class member variables.

Could you please go into a little more detail?
Sorry for the accidental click :( Is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: @TorbenC, In the class's definition in the header, you declare it with `static short int HitPoints;`, and in the class's implementation file (if each class has its own impl file), you define it by saying `short int PlayerStatistics::HitPoints = 20;`

Comment: YES!! Thank you so much, we were under the impression that the static member variables HAD to be initialized directly after class. Thank you so much (both of you!), huge relief!

Comment: @TorbenC, Yes, this is more related to the issue at hand, but keep in mind include guards should generally be put around your headers. Trying to include one twice that defines a class without guards doesn't go down well with the compiler.

Comment: Alright, thank you again. Include/Header Guards are actually involved in about 2-3 chapters from now in our books so we may just skip over to that chapter real quick and learn about them seeing as they are needed for things like this. Thank you!